# Cloning a FileList object in JavaScript for file upload?

Tags: javascript, html, object, file-upload, cloning

Alright, here is my situation. I have a JavaScript class that deals with AJAX form submissions and other related synchronous and asynchronous requests. It gathers data, then sets this data to a temporary storage for the request and then makes the request with the temporary storage data.

For example:

- User starts building a request, puts NAME and LAST NAME to the form
- This data is put into an object variable SUBMITDATA
- When request is made then this data is cloned to another variable TEMPSUBMITDATA
- Once the request is complete then the data that was used to make the request is still available (for debugging or other purposes)

This means that if two requests are ongoing at the same time through the same object, then I can still access the data that was used to make these requests.

Everything works as expected, until I want to use HTML5 FileList and FormData. While I can clone objects in JavaScript through relative ease, I cannot clone FileList. Here is an example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // This method is used to clone data objects
        function clone(object){
            if(object==null || typeof(object)!=='object'){
                return object;
            }
            // This line throws the error when FileList data is attempted to be cloned
            var tmp=object.constructor();
            for(var key in object){
                tmp[key]=clone(object[key]);
            }
            return tmp;
        }

        // This is an example data storage
        var submitData=new Object();
        submitData['some-data']='abc';

        function uploader(files){

            submitData['my-files']=files;

            // This clones the object and leads to the error because of FileList
            var tempSubmitData=clone(submitData);

            // HERE WOULD THE ACTUAL FORM SUBMIT HAPPEN
            // THIS EXAMPLE IS SHOWN FOR EASIER READING OF
            // THE PROBLEM EXPLAINED ABOVE

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="file" name="myfile" value="" onchange="uploader(this.files);"/>
</body>
```

This leads me to my question, can I - at all - clone this type of data in any way so I could store it until the request is complete? Or is really the only way to make a new object every single time?

The new object solution is not good for me since my class works like a separate application, it has a log and other data that is useful for request tracking later on and it works really well in every case - until now that I stumbled upon HTML5 FileList and FormData use.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

If you're using `jQuery` you can use the `extend` method to clone an object like this.

```
var clonedObject = $.extend(true,{},yourObject);
```

If you're not maybe you can use in this case the native `Object.create()`

```
var clonedObject = Object.create(yourObject);
```

The last is not a copy (but an **empty** object with the *properties* and *functions* of the former one as part of it's prototype, if i'm not mistaken), but it's similar and I think it would work for you in this case.